# Retrieval of Area Shapes - Limit Resolution - HERE Maps API [here-api]

Tags: here-api

Is there a way to limit the size/resolution when retrieving area shapes from the here.com API?

I love the highly detailed resolution, but unfortunately the size of the shapes is killing my application performance and taking forever to load on the map.

Comment: Which API are you using? Please specify your request and response.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a sample request. I am pulling shapes for Country, State, County, City or Zip.

Here is a sample of me asking for shape of Santa Clara County.

https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?searchtext=US%2BCA%2BSanta%20Clara%2BCounty&additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,county&app_id=ID&app_code=CODE&gen=9

Answer (score 0):

Here currently doesn't provide any means to limit the resolution of the WKTShapeResponse. However, you can limit the resolution at your end by writing an algorithm to smooth the points before rendering it on the map.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's a lot of extra work for me to do that, but will look at figuring that out. Feature request, it would be awesome if you could specify a smoothing value when requesting the shape from the API. Would make things very easy!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We shall keep the team informed. Happy Coding!